# iOS UILabel rotating issue

Tags: ios, view, rotation, uilabel

I have an issue with a UILabel acting funny when I try to rotate it. I am programmatically creating the label in code to be in the center of my view and am currently hard setting the values of it. What I am trying to do is get text to be rotated and set on the left side of the screen so that it is aligned with the left border. If I do `textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` then the text is rotated properly but is upside down. However, when I do `textY.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);` then the text looks to be rotated and displayed on an angle instead of being flush with the border. I have pasted the full code snippet below and appreciate any advice.

```
CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 40, 40);
UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
text.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
text.text = @"Home";
[self.view addSubview:text];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:text];
```

Comment: you said upside down, you want the text to read from bottom to top or top to bottom?  (I assume you want the text to be rotated up and down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the text to read from bottom to top

```
E
M
O
H
```

You can do so like this:

```
text.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2*3);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A question I have for this though is why the multiplication by 3? Why not the M_PI_4 as I would assume that would be the next logical step?

Comment: M_PI_4 is pie/4, M_PI_2 is pie/2.  around the whole cirlce is 2PI, so one step of M_PI_2 is 1/4, and 3 steps of M_PI_2, is 3/4, the other side.

Comment: Is each charater('H', 'O', 'M', 'E') rotated?

Comment: no not individually, but yes, the whole string of letters are rotated.